# Saving a CSV into a blob

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I would like to save CSV files that users upload to a blob. I would than like to retrieve the CSV file out of the blob in a format that I can use with the ruby CSV library. Any ideas on how I can accomplish that?

Comment: http://mattberther.com/2007/10/19/uploading-files-to-a-database-using-rails

Comment: Do you even want to store them in a database? Why not storing the filename and write the "blobs" to disk...zipped. Or use amazon or azure to store the data. Otherwise your database needs to be scaled soon (if many files are uploaded) just because you fill it with data which has no business of being in a database unless you want to full text search it;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add a field to your model with datatype `:text` **(because that's what a CSV is, not binary)**. Let's say your model is called `Record` and the field is called `csv`:

```
record = Record.new
record.csv = File.read 'path/to/csv'
record.save
#... later...
CSV.parse record.csv # => here's your csv
```

Questions?

Comment: My main question is, will this work for large CSV files? (say 100,000 rows)?

Comment: Most likely yes, the variable length text data type in, for example, postgresql, allows about 1GB. Find out what database you're using and google around to see what the limitation on it is.